# Custom Taxonomy for custom post type template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

After assign a custom taxonomy (i.e. teams) to a custom post type (team), I've created the taxonomy-teams.php template but the custom post type doesn't seems to be specified to the $wp_query.

I would like to avoid to create an additional query or to alter the query_post (i.e.: `query_posts("post_type=team&".$query_string);`) which is a bit hacky.

Any ways to do that ??

Comment: bit unclear, you have assigned the taxonomy to teams (using register taxonomy) and the archive is displaying non teams posts? Or are you just looking to get the post type on the archive page?

Comment: I have assigned the teams taxonomy to the team custom post type. The teams taxonomy is kinda like a team category and the team custom post type is to create the team members.

So if I access the page /teams/directors/ my page is empty because the custom post type is not specified in the wp_query but I made sure to specify it...